# Shakespeare Variable Assignments Not Working

Tags: compiler-errors, shakespeare-lang

I have looked through several Shakespeare documentations, but I cannot figure out how to make my Shakespeare program work.

I have tried the following:

```
Shakespeare, A Program.
Romeo, A young man.
Juliet, a young woman
Act I: A test of variables.
Scene I: The first scene.
[Enter Romeo and Juliet]
Hamlet: You are as stupid as a smelly big flower!
```

(This should set Juliet to 4, because smelly = *2, big = *2, and flower = 1)

```
Juliet: Proceed to Scene II.
[Exeunt]
Scene I: The second scene.
[Enter Romeo and Juliet]
Juliet: Am I better than you?
Romeo: If so, you are as intelligent as the square root of Juliet.
Romeo: Open your heart.
```

This should return 2, which is Juliet's value. Unfortunately, this just gives a compiler error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the beginning, you only defined Romeo and Juliet, and had 2 Scene I's. I think that what you meant to do is

```
Shakespeare, A Program.

Romeo, A young man.
Juliet, a young woman.

Act I: A test of variables.

Scene I: The first scene.
[Enter Romeo and Juliet]
Romeo: <<This is important, because Hamlet is not defined!
You are as stupid as a smelly big flower!
Juliet: Proceed to Scene II.
[Exeunt]  

Scene II: The second scene. <<You need to change it to Scene II!
[Enter Romeo and Juliet] 
Juliet: Am I better than you?
Romeo: If so, you are as intelligent as the square root of Juliet.
Romeo: Open your heart.
[Exeunt]
```

This should return 2.

Comment: For amusement I have created my own SPL "IDE"  and tested this program with it.  See the program called "Stack Overflow example" [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=SPL)

Comment: Wow, this is great!

Answer (score 1):

Also, it is not typical practice by the compiler to have all characters exeunt at the end of a scene, if said characters are going to be brought back for the next scene. Also, the "proceed to scene 2 isn't necessary (but it is helpful).
eg

```
Juliet: Proceed to Scene II

Scene II: The second scene.
....
```